# Текущее время с точностью до миллисекунд

Tags: c++

В логирование хочу добавить время записи лога в формате: гггг.мм.дд. // чч.мм.сс//ммм ,
где ммм - миллисекунды. 
Можно это сделать средствами с++ без ручного пересчета секунд, прошедших с 1900 года? Имеется в виду узнать **ВСЮ** дату целиком. Миллисекунды, понятно, считаются отдельно.

Comment: на с++ должно быть возможно даже с точностью до наносекунд. это же с++, а не какой-то там пхп.

Comment: @Sergey Не, выдавать наносекунды - легко. Вопрос в большей степени заключался в том, что не надо делать пересчет с нулевого комп.времени. Ну и желательно, чтобы стандартная функция сама считала миллисекунды, а не отдельно, другими средствами.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Решение для винды с "честными" миллисекундами:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    SYSTEMTIME st;

    GetLocalTime(&st);

    printf( "%d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d.%03d", 
             st.wYear,
             st.wMonth, 
             st.wDay,                      
             st.wHour, 
             st.wMinute, 
             st.wSecond,
             st.wMilliseconds );    
}
```

> 2016-04-13 18:26:45.266

<kbd>[Результат выполнения](http://rextester.com/PIOL9046)</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

Для *nix (проверял в Ubuntu) и Windows (проверял в MinGW) в качестве измерителя времени можно использовать POSIX.1-2001  [gettimeofday](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettimeofday.2.html)  (правда, уже устаревшую к 8-му году, с рекомендацией POSIX.1-2008 использовать [clock_gettime](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html) (которая  отсутствует в доступном мне MinGW)).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#define DATEFMT "YYYY.MM.DD//hh:mm:ss//MMM"

#ifdef WIN32
struct tm *
gmtime_r (time_t *t, struct tm *r)
{
  struct tm *res = gmtime(t);

  if (res) {
    *r = *res;
    res = r;
  }

  return r;
}

struct tm *
localtime_r (time_t *t, struct tm *r)
{
  struct tm *res = localtime(t);

  if (res) {
    *r = *res;
    res = r;
  }

  return r;
}
#endif


int 
main (int ac, char **av)
{
  struct timeval tv;
  struct timezone tz;
  struct tm tm;

  gettimeofday(&tv, &tz);  // вместо tz можно 0, если сами не собираетесь с TZ играться

  //  gmtime_r(&tv.tv_sec, &tm); // UTC
  localtime_r(&tv.tv_sec, &tm);
  char now[sizeof(DATEFMT) + 1] = "strftime() error";
  size_t l = strftime(now, sizeof(now), "%Y.%m.%d//%H.%M.%S//", &tm);
  if (l)  
    sprintf(now + l, "%03d", (int)tv.tv_usec / 1000); // я думаю, что в таких задачах округление излишне 

  return puts(now) == EOF;
}
```

Оказывается, кроме отсутствия `localtime_r()`/`gmtime_r()` еще и `strftime()` в винде не понимает `%G` и `%T`.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <chrono>

using namespace std::chrono;

//main...

milliseconds ms = duration_cast< milliseconds >(
    system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()
);
```

Comment: Да уж, тут действительно не надо пересчитывать секунды, тут надо уже миллисекунды пересчитывать)

Comment: @Dmitry Это единственный ответ, который соответствует Вашему вопросу. Это на С++ без ручного пересчета. Ну а то, что Вы не понимаете разницы между С++ и Си,  и, как следствие, не поняли написанного, то это не повод для усмешки. А скорее повод Вам задуматься над формулировкой своего вопроса и, наверное, заняться изучением С++.

Comment: @MaxZS, а может это повод задуматься, а стоит ли вообще (а если и стоит, то в какой степени) использовать С++.

Comment: @avp Может и так. Поэтому и написал, что есть смысл задуматься над формулировкой вопроса (как минимум над указанным тегом). Ну а если противопоставлять Си и С++. То есть достоинства и недостатки как у одного, так и у второго. А по поводу вот такого вот дебильного синтаксиса, так это нужно задуматься любителям буста, из которого этот шлак и перекочевывает в стандарт С++. Но коли он уже перекочевал, то приходится использовать. А вот сам буст, пока он таким макаром не перекочует в стандарт, я юзать ну очень не желаю и не буду.

Comment: @MaxZS так это же означает количество миллисекунд с загрузки системы. А мне надо было еще год, месяц, день, текущий час, минуты и секунды.

Answer (score 1):

Подойдёт решение, которое только для Windows?

```
/* strftime example */
#include <stdio.h>      /* puts */
#include <time.h>       /* time_t, struct tm, time, localtime,   strftime */
#include <Windows.h>

int main ()
{
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;
    char buffer [80];

    time (&rawtime);
    timeinfo = localtime (&rawtime);

    strftime (buffer,80,"Now it's %Y.%m.%d // %H.%M.%S // ",timeinfo);
    printf("%s", buffer);
    printf("%d\n", GetTickCount() % 1000);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Да, подойдет, спасибо. Только `localtime` устарела.

Comment: @Dmitry,  только (если, конечно, придираться) тут уже все-таки не те миллисекунды, что были во время вызова `time()`.

Comment: @avp это не особо большую роль играет в записи логов)

Comment: @Dmitry, тогда, по большому счету, миллисекунды вообще не нужны.

Comment: @avp у меня логи в разных частях программы пишутся в разные файлы. + все происходит в нескольких потоках. С миллисекундами удобнее сопоставлять данные. Расхождение в 50 миллисекунд сыграет незаметную роль.

Comment: @Dmitry, понятно, тогда другое дело. А такой точности для определения очередности событий достаточно? Может лучше выводить микросекунды, которые у Вас все равно есть?

Comment: @avp можно, да, думаю, пока миллисекунд хватит. Если уж очень припечет, то можно и наносекунды задействовать)